# How can I open dired with reversed sorting of name, and with the cursor on the first line?

Tags: dired

I use the following initial code to open one om my frequently used folders:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-6") (lambda() 
    (interactive)
    (find-file (format "C:/Users/%s/notes" user-login-name) )))
```

If I left point at line 16 last time I killed the dired buffer for the folder, dired will open my folder with point at line 16.

How can I always open this folder with point at line 1 (..) ?

How can I alway open this folder with reversed name sorting ?

**EDIT** (2019-07-17--08-55-47):
my questions were not complete. I need this:

1) keep the two links "." and ".." on the first and second line, as normal

2) then place all my folders below the two first lines

3) then sort all files below the folders, sorted in reverse order

Adding an "r" to (setq dired-listing-switches "-alr") sorts 1) and 2) to the very bottom, not very practical for me.

Comment: To get reverse name sorting, use `SWITCHES` arg to `dired`, specifying switch `-r`. `M-x man` `ls` is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see the "point at line 16" behavior you see: every time I open a directory after killing the buffer, the cursor is on the first file (third line in the buffer, with the default `-al` switches). Are you sure you are killing the buffer?

For the reverse sorting, as @Drew points out, calling `dired` with a prefix argument (`C-u M-x dired`) allows you to specify the `SWITCHES` argument: you can add an `r` to the default `-al` and get a reversed listing. If you want to have reverse listings *always*, add this line to your init file:

```
 (setq dired-listing-switches "-alr")
```

or customize the `dired-listing-switches` variable.

If you insist on getting to `dired` through `find-file`, things get a bit harder: I would let-bind the above variable in your function:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-6") (lambda() 
    (interactive)
    (let ((dired-listing-switches "-alr"))
        (find-file (format "C:/Users/%s/notes" user-login-name)))))
```

If you want to go to the beginning of the buffer every time you press `C-6` (whether the buffer exists already or not), you can add a `(goto-char (point-min))` to your function:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-6") (lambda() 
    (interactive)
    (let ((dired-listing-switches "-alr"))
        (find-file (format "C:/Users/%s/notes" user-login-name))
        (goto-char (point-min)))))
```

EDIT: re.the revised sorting spec - I don't think that's possible with `ls` switches. You can try adding `--group-directories-first` to the `dired-listing-switchtes`, but the `-r` will reverse the order of the directories as well, so all the directories will appear first in reverse order (so `.` and `..` will be at the end of the list of directories) and then all the files will appear in reverse order. I'm not even sure that `--group-directories-first` is available on Windows.

Comment: Thanks! It seems you'r right.  "The point at line 16" behavior did not turn up again.

Comment: The -r switch  have two side effect, given in my EDIT comment above, it makes both the ".", ".." and all folders to be sorted to the bottom. I need them in the top.

Comment: Your added code line, that with the "let" function, seems to have a mismatch of "(" and ")" that is not corrected for further down in the code. Im I right?

Comment: You are right: I was missing a closing paren at the end of each form. Fixed now. Thanks!